# Why do I get "Pseudo-hashes are deprecated"?

Tags: perl

I have this code

```
if (defined($xml->{account}->{p}) == '2') {
...
}
```

which gives me this warning

```
Pseudo-hashes are deprecated at a.pl line 48.
```

The problem is that in some cases `$xml->{account}->{p}` doesn't exist, which was why I added the `defined` function.

`$xml` is an object, if that makes a difference?

How can this be fixed, so Perl doesn't complain?

Comment: `if (exists($xml->{account}->{p}) == '2'){...}`

Comment: I would be surprised if the defined() function (or the exists() function) ever returned 2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either `$xml` or `$xml->{account}` is an ARRAY, not a HASH (you can use `ref` to check this, see `perldoc -f ref`).  Perl had a now-deprecated feature called "pseudo-hashes" that allowed special arrays to be accessed via hash syntax.  If you care about the history, you can google around for it or look at an older-edition camel book.